# Apply a rolling function by group in r (zoo, data.table)

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

I am having trouble doing something fairly simple: apply a rolling function (standard deviation) by group in a data.table. 
My problem is that when I use a data.table with rollapply by some column, data.table recycles the observations as noted in the warning message below. I would like to get NAs for the observations that are outside of the window instead of recycling the standard deviations.

This is my approach so far using iris, and a rolling window of size 2, aligned to the right:

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

A <- iris
setDT(A)
A[,stdev := rollapply(Petal.Width, width = 2, sd, align = 'right', partial = F),by = Species]
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(A, , `:=`(stdeev, rollapply(Petal.Width, width = 2,  :
  Supplied 49 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 50 in column 'stdeev' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).
2: In `[.data.table`(A, , `:=`(stdeev, rollapply(Petal.Width, width = 2,  :
  Supplied 49 items to be assigned to group 2 of size 50 in column 'stdeev' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).
3: In `[.data.table`(A, , `:=`(stdeev, rollapply(Petal.Width, width = 2,  :
  Supplied 49 items to be assigned to group 3 of size 50 in column 'stdeev' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).

> A
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species     stdeev      stdev
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa 0.00000000 0.00000000
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa 0.00000000 0.00000000
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa 0.00000000 0.00000000
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa 0.00000000 0.00000000
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa 0.14142136 0.14142136
 ---                                                                                  
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica 0.28284271 0.28284271
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica 0.07071068 0.07071068
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica 0.21213203 0.21213203
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 0.35355339 0.35355339
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica 0.42426407 0.42426407
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `fill=NA` to `rollapply`. This will ensure that a vector of length 50 (rather than 49) is returned, with `NA` as the first value (since `align="right"`), avoiding recycling.

```
A[,stdev := rollapply(Petal.Width, width=2, sd, align='right', partial=F, fill=NA), by=Species]
```

> ```
>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species      stdev
> 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa         NA
> 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa 0.00000000
> 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa 0.00000000
> ...
> 51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor         NA
> 52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor 0.07071068
> 53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor 0.00000000
> ...
> 101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica         NA
> 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica 0.42426407
> 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica 0.14142136
> ```

Comment: thank you! What does align really do? I thought it started counting the window from the left, so I would have expected two NA before the first value

Comment: When you align right, it places the first rolling value at the right end of the window, so a window length of two will give NA for the first value. Align left will give NA for the last value.

Comment: so if it was width 3, and align right, I would see two NA's before the first value?

Comment: Yes. And if you used center, there would be one NA at the beginning and one at the end. Try `rollapply(1:20, sd, fill=NA)` with different values for `width` and `align` and you'll quickly see how it works.